# Simulating browser traffic for Windows

Tags: c#, windows, web-services, webserver

I have a few scripts that make calls to a webservice.  These scripts are inserted in to a web page via an IHttpHandler.  Idealy, i would like to simulate a bunch of people requesting the page, downloading the script and run any ajax request while the browser session is alive.  I havent been able to find any tools that actually run the javascript after its been downloaded.  Are there any tools that do this?  Are there any tools I can use that simulate a request that dont require Java?

Answer (score 3):

You could give [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [WatiN](http://watin.org/) a try.

Comment: WatiN is good for running the full browser experience, but it can run a little slow on the browser side so it may not be great for simulating any type of load.